# Button Inside Fragment won't work even without errors

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, fragment

My button inside the fragment is not working. There are no errors and I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class GenApp extends Fragment {
EditText etBillAmt;
Spinner spinType, spinHours, spinDays, spinWeeks;
EditText etWattage, etHour, etDay, etWeek, etMonth;
Button btnCalculate;
String BillAmountS,h,d,w;
int i,dfrm,wfrm;
double BillAmount, PKwh, WattDouble, CPH, CPD, CPW, CPM, hrfrm;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.genapp, container, false);

    h = "8";
    d = "7";
    w = "4";
    etBillAmt = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etBillAmt);
    spinType = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinType);
    spinHours = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinHours);
    spinDays = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinDays);
    spinWeeks = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinWeeks);
    etWattage = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etWattage);
    etHour = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etHour);
    etDay = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etDay);
    etWeek = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etWeek);
    etMonth = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etMonth);
    btnCalculate = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);

    final String[] apptypearray = {"AIR COOLER/HUMIDIFIER", "BLENDER", "CELLPHONE CHARGER", "CFL(10 WATTS)", "CFL(18 WATTS)", "CHRISTMAS LIGHT(100 BULBS W/O BLINKER)", "CHRISTMAS LIGHT(100 BULBS W/ BLINKER)",
    "CLOTHES DRYER(HEATER)", "CLOTHES DRYER(MOTOR)", "COFFEE MAKER", "COMPUTER PRINTER", "COMPUTER W/MONITOR", "FLAT IRON(STANDARD)", "FLAT IRON(DELUXE)", "FLOOR POLISHER(STANDARD)", "FLOOR POLISHER(DELUXE)",
    "FLUORESCENT LAMP 21' (20 WATTS)", "FLUORESCENT LAMP 48' (40 WATTS)", "HAIR DRYER", "INCANDESCENT BULB (25 WATTS)", "INCANDESCENT BULB (50 WATTS)", "INCANDESCENT (100 WATTS)", "RECHARGEABLE LIGHTS/FANS", "SEWING MACHINE",
    "VACUUM CLEANER", "WAHING MACHINE AUTOMATIC (6 KG)", "WASHING MACHINE AUTOMATIC (10 KG)", "WASHING MACHINE TWIN TUB (6 KG)", "WASHING MACHINE TWIN TUB (10 KG)", "WATER DISPENSER(COOLING)", "WATER DISPENSER(HEATING)",
            "WATER HEATER", "WATER HEATER (PORTABLE)", "OTHER GENERAL APPLIANCES"};
    final double[] wattagearray = {65, 300, 6, 10, 18, 56, 16, 1600, 250, 600, 175, 225, 600, 1000, 200, 360, 32, 53, 320, 25, 50, 100, 12, 75, 800, 527, 1035, 277, 583, 90, 550, 3000, 1600};
    final double[] KWh = {0.33, 5.18, 6.64, 8.08, 10.12, 10.50, 10.87, 11.54, 11.80};
    final String[] hoursarray = {"15 minutes","30 minutes","45 minutes","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24"};
    final String[] daysarray = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};
    final String[] weeksarray = {"1","2","3","4"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, apptypearray);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinType.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    spinType.setPrompt("Please choose your Appliance");
    spinType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            for (i = 0; i<apptypearray.length; i++){
                if(spinType.getItemAtPosition(position) == apptypearray[i]) {

                    try {
                        etWattage.setText(String.valueOf(wattagearray[i]));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Missing Entries", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            etHour.setText("");
            etDay.setText("");
            etWeek.setText("");
            etMonth.setText("");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter<String> HourArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hoursarray);
    HourArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinHours.setAdapter(HourArrayAdapter);
    int GP1 = HourArrayAdapter.getPosition(h);
    spinHours.setSelection(GP1);
    spinHours.setPrompt("Hours Used Per Day");
    spinHours.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> houradapterView, View view, int hpos, long l) {
            for(int hctr = 0; hctr<hoursarray.length; hctr++){
                if(spinHours.getItemAtPosition(hpos) == hoursarray[0]) {
                    hrfrm = 0.25;
                }
                else if (spinHours.getItemAtPosition(hpos) == hoursarray[1]) {
                    hrfrm = 0.5;
                }
                else if (spinHours.getItemAtPosition(hpos) == hoursarray[2]) {
                    hrfrm = 0.75;
                }
                else if (spinHours.getItemAtPosition(hpos) == hoursarray[hctr]) {
                    hrfrm = Double.parseDouble(hoursarray[hctr]);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> DayArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, daysarray);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinDays.setAdapter(DayArrayAdapter);
    int GP2 = DayArrayAdapter.getPosition(d);
    spinDays.setSelection(GP2);
    spinDays.setPrompt("Days Used Per Week");
    spinDays.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> DayadapterView, View view, int dpos, long l) {
            for(int dctr = 0; dctr<daysarray.length;dctr++)
            {
                if(spinDays.getItemAtPosition(dpos)==daysarray[dctr])
                {
                    dfrm = Integer.parseInt(daysarray[dctr]);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> WeekArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, weeksarray);
    WeekArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinWeeks.setAdapter(WeekArrayAdapter);
    int GP3 = WeekArrayAdapter.getPosition(w);
    spinWeeks.setSelection(GP3);
    spinWeeks.setPrompt("Weeks used per Month");
    spinWeeks.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> WeekadapterView, View view, int wpos, long l) {
            for(int wkctr = 0; wkctr<weeksarray.length; wkctr++){
                if(spinWeeks.getItemAtPosition(wpos)==weeksarray[wkctr]) {
                    wfrm = Integer.parseInt(weeksarray[wkctr]);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootView) {
            try {
                WattDouble = Double.parseDouble(etWattage.getText().toString());
                BillAmountS = etBillAmt.getText().toString();
                BillAmount = Double.parseDouble(BillAmountS);
                if (BillAmount >= 0 && BillAmount <= 108) {
                    PKwh = KWh[0];
                } else if (BillAmount >= 109 && BillAmount <= 338) {
                    PKwh = KWh[1];
                } else if (BillAmount >= 339 && BillAmount <= 573) {
                    PKwh = KWh[2];
                } else if (BillAmount >= 574 && BillAmount <= 1021) {
                    PKwh = KWh[3];
                } else if (BillAmount >= 1022 && BillAmount <= 2109) {
                    PKwh = KWh[4];
                } else if (BillAmount >= 2110 && BillAmount <= 3271) {
                    PKwh = KWh[5];
                } else if (BillAmount >= 3272 && BillAmount <= 4625) {
                    PKwh = KWh[6];
                } else if (BillAmount >= 4626 && BillAmount <= 7684) {
                    PKwh = KWh[7];
                } else if (BillAmount >= 7685) {
                    PKwh = KWh[8];
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Amount", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                /*Cost per hour = Rate x [(appliance wattage x 0.8 x 0.8) + (appliance wattage x 0.2)] / 1000)*/
                CPH = PKwh * (WattDouble / 1000);
                CPD = CPH * hrfrm;
                CPW = CPD * dfrm;
                CPM = CPW * wfrm;

                etHour.setText("PhP " + String.format("%.2f", CPH));
                etDay.setText("PhP " + String.format("%.2f", CPD));
                etWeek.setText("PhP " + String.format("%.2f", CPW));
                etMonth.setText("PhP " + String.format("%.2f", CPM));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Entry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


            }
    }

});
    return rootView;
}
}
```

The original view on the on click was: `(view v)` and I read something off the internet saying it should be the same name as my `inflater.inflate` so I changed it to `(view rootView)`. Nothing happened to both of them. Button still won't work.

Comment: Where and how do you initialize btnCalculate?

Comment: btnCalculate = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
I initialized it right after the final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.genapp, container, false); line. Thank You!

Comment: If it is not too long, can you post the full onCreateView code (or a simplified version) and also your xml layout? Are there any layouts which may be blocking the click event?

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.jmljrkss.jarkassmeralco.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="CALCULATE"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etWattage"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etWattage"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etMonth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etHour" />

Comment: those are my xml codes for the button. thank you!

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please do not add solved to title instead post an answer or accept the answer that is working for you see [tour] to learn more

Answer (score 1):

Try to Check whether you are getting this message

```
btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Onclick Listeber button calculate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: It means that your click event is working, most probably there is something  wrong with the logic and it is not producing the output you are expecting. My suggestion: Try to debug your program using breakpoints.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help guys :)

Comment: @JmJarkass Change the title to solved so that others don't waste time again and accept the answer if it solved your problem. One more thing you should use application context as little as possible. If activity context is avliable then use that.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized your button.
First initialize it

```
Button btnCalculate = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.value);
btnCalculate.setOnClickListener( now ur function)
```

Comment: I already initialized the button right after the Final View rootView line. should I initialize it again inside the onClick? Thank you!

Comment: No if you have initialized it then u dont need to initialize it again

Comment: could I have missed any codes? other than the initialization? thank you!